# Complicated RecyclerView issue. Eliding some fields

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Trying to build a recyclerview where one of the widgets (a TextView holding a date) is gone (View.GONE) depending on a variable. What I have for the item in the recyclerview looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/historyItemLayout"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/historyItemDateTV"
        android:background="@color/grey_300"
        android:text="09-24-2020"
        />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/historyItemTeamNameTV"
                android:text="@string/team_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/historyItemPlayerNameTV"
                android:text="@string/player_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

  </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

There is a list of entries that each holds all of the data that will be pushed to the adapter. So, each entry into that list holds a date field, a player name a team name and some other data (elided here for brevity).

What I want to do is display the date the first time it comes up, but hide (actually, View.GONE) it until the date changes.

Here is an example:

Entry1 2020-09-27 other data

Entry2 2020-09-27 other data

Entry3 2020-09-27 other data

Entry4 2020-08-01 other data

Entry5 2020-05-05 other data

So, for this, I would display a line showing 2020-09-27, then have three lines under it that show the data for the three entries that each have 2020-09-27 as their date. Then, I'd display another line holding just the date 2020-08-01 then the data for that date on the line following, and finally display another line with just 2020-05-05 and another line with the data for that final date.

I've got all of the data sorted correctly using a comparator for insertion into my adapter, but how upon display do I check to see if the date line needs to be hidden or not?

Answer (score 0):

Think I have the answer...will verify.

In the RecyclerView I'll save off the last date I display, and check that in onBindViewHolder. If the dates match, I'll hide that TextView (or perhaps its layout).

Something like this:

```
    //Now handle hiding of extraneous dates
    if(lastDate == child.date) {
        holder.dateTV.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    else {
        lastDate = child.date
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood that correctly (a screenshot probably would have explained it better).

But I think, that you should use `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`, in order not to mess up the whole layout. `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.GONE` both literally do what they say - and when the parent node (the recycler-item) has `wrap_content` set, this may result in a mess (uneven heights).